# Am I "Allowed" to add a default constraint directly to DB in Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm

Wondering if anyone can help a total newbie to Dynamics 365. Have started working on an existing implementation of Dynamics 365 (on premise) and am told by current developers that under no circumstances can I amend a column in a table for one of our entities directly on the DB. I am simply wanting to default an INT column to value 1.

They tell me "Dynamics is a black box and you will be breaking the law if you amend directly". This can't be true can it?

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 2):

Building on what Josh said, it is true that the Dynamics SQL database is a black box. Everything must be done through the API with the exception of creating custom indexes on tables and reading from the "Filtered" views.

(And with the new [T-SQL endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/cds-sql-query) in preview for the online product, you're able to run SQL `select` queries against an online org.)

The reason for this that all [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/event-framework#available-events) in Dynamics go through the "platform" via messages. For example, you might have plugin or workflow automation that triggers on the Update of an Account. When the platform receives the "Update" message for an Account, it searches for subscribers to that event and runs any subscribed processes. If you write a change directly to an Account record in SQL, you deprive the platform of the opportunity to run its processes for that event.

And it is good to note that Microsoft uses the same event framework for internal events. So, if you say, "Well, I have no custom plugins or workflows running on the Update message for Accounts so I can edit Accounts directly in SQL." By doing so you'd still risk breaking an internal Microsoft process that triggers on that event.

In a nutshell the platform's need to process ALL events is why direct updates to the database are unsupported. If you do them, Microsoft will refuse to support your system.

Another consideration is that if you ever want to move to the Dynamics Online, writing to the database isn't even possible, so you'd have to redo any automation that relied on that. This is another reason why everyone generally accepts the need to customize their system in the supported way.

Do people occasionally do unsupported things, with good justification? Yes, perhaps most commonly in making unsupported changes to the UI. Even so, writing directly to the database is among the highest offenses to be avoided.

Back to your scenario... it can be jarring to discover that the SQL database is off limits for any direct writing or schema changes. Fortunately Dynamics provides many other automation "hooks" including client-side JavaScript, Business Rules, Power Automate Flows, workflows, and plugins (synchronous and asynchronous).

To set a default value in the UI, the options include a Business Rule and JavaScript. To set a default value in the database, a synchronous workflow or plugin would do the trick.

The [Developer Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/overview) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for answers, even more so for explanations of why and pointers to docs to help me out. Much appreciated gents.

Comment: Much better answer than mine - this one should be the accepted answer! Good extra info and links here

Comment: Thanks @JoshPainter!

Answer (score 1):

This would be considered an “unsupported” customization by Microsoft. If it breaks something in the logic of the app, Microsoft won’t help you fix it. If you ever move to Online instead of On-premise, you won’t have this ability. The current developers are battle-hardened and are trying to help you. This is a very bad idea - better would be to create a plug-in on Create of that entity that sets up default values for null fields. This way your logic is in the app with all the other custom logic and is supported.