# Microsoft CRM 4.0 shows error after adding trigger with email alert on IncidentBase table (Cases) in SQL

Tags: sql-server, email, triggers, dynamics-crm, alert

I have been trying to find a solution on this problem for hours with no luck. Let me explain the situation.

There is a Microsoft CRM 4.0 server that we need to add an email alert whenever a user cancels a case. There are 2 possible ways to do that, first is through the "OnSave" event on the Case Form through the Customizations menu (which we have access to) and second by adding a trigger directly on the MS SQL DB of the CRM app that will fire anytime a user does exactly what the trigger says.

So I went with the second option and while I created the trigger, set the Database Mail (which works perfect) and tested the trigger by manually updating the table contents through the SQL Management Studio (the email alert worked like a charm), when I try to cancel the case through the CRM form, I get a generic error page from CRM like the one following and it doesn't complete the cancellation.

[image]

If I disable the trigger, everything works fine again. Also, if I change the trigger script and only the part of the email send (EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail) with something else generic like inserting a row in another table, CRM works like it should and it finishes the cancellation of the case. It's obvious that there is something in the email sending that messes things up with the CRM.

I just hope that there is somebody in the community that have worked with MS CRM 4.0 in the past and can give me some advice. I don't mind using the first method also through the Event Customization if someone can give me some pointers. I believe Javascript is used for scripting in this environment but I think that setting an email alert there is way out of the scope of this environment. Let's hope I am wrong...

Thanx in advance.

Comment: `sp_send_dbmail` returns InfoMessages that CRM may not be prepared for. Consider alternatives for triggering your mail messages, such as inserting records into another table that is monitored for new records, or using Service Broker queues.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion. I created another table in which a new record was added when the trigger from the first table is fired, then a second trigger on the new table is firing when the new record is inserted and tries to send the email but unfortunately I get the same exact error on CRM. I haven't worked with Service Broker queues but I will look into it as the last alternative. If you have any pointers, please share. Thanx again.

Comment: Nesting triggers like that won't work because the InfoMessages will just be getting sent back to CRM via the nested trigger instead. What I meant is to have your existing trigger record the necessary information for message sending into a different table and then have a regularly scheduled process detect the new records to invoke sp_send_dbmail from there.

Answer (score 0):

In my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232612/am-i-allowed-to-add-a-default-constraint-directly-to-db-in-dynamics-365/65235715#65235715) I described how and why changes directly to the Dynamics SQL database are unsupported. TL;DR - directly modifying the database is unsupported, all changes must go through the API.

Since you're on v4.0 the whole system is unsupported. But, if your organization ever plans to upgrade, staying supported always helps the cause.

It has been a while since I did anything with v4, but a [workflow](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274783/Create-a-Workflow-in-Microsoft-Dynamic-CRM-4-0) might be the best way to do what you want. JavaScript can also do what you want, but is probably a lot more complicated and only fires when you're working on the form, whereas a workflow fires anytime including imports, etc.